# xarray cannot directly convert an xarray.Dataset into a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

I'm experiencing an error that I cannot seem to resolve when attempting to convert from a Dataset to array when using xarray. I'm encountering this because I'm attempting to add a time dimension to a netcdf file (open netcdf, add a timestamp that is the same across all data, save out netcdf).

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

scriptpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

outputfile = scriptpath + '\\20210629_deadgrass.aus.nc'

times= pd.to_datetime(str(yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')))
time_da = xr.Dataset({"time": times})

arr = xr.open_dataset(outputfile)
ds = arr.to_array()
dst = ds.expand_dims(time=time_da) #errors here
```

The error I'm receiving is

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
cannot directly convert an xarray.Dataset into a numpy array. Instead, create an xarray.DataArray first, either with indexing on the Dataset or by invoking the `to_array()` method.
  File "Z:\UpdateAussieGRASS.py", line 101, in <module>
    dst = ds.expand_dims(time=time_da)
```

I can't seem to work out what I'm doing wrong with `to_array()` in the second last line. Examples of to_array() are [here](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/reshaping.html). Autogenerated documentation is [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_array.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ds` is already an `xarray.DataArray`. The error occurs on this line:

```
dst = ds.expand_dims(time=time_da) #errors here
```

Because while `ds` is a `DataArray`, `time_da` is not. This should work:

```
dst = ds.expand_dims(time=time_da.to_array())
```

Comment: Thank you. So, I've moved on to a different problem with that line using your modification. ```Exception has occurred: ValueError
at least one array or dtype is required
  File "Z:\UpdateAussieGRASS.py", line 104, in <module>
    dst = ds.expand_dims(time=time_da.to_array())```.
Shouldn't an array be present since we just did a to_array?

Comment: @anakaine, is that still an error ?  @Kraigolas, is there doc on what `to_array` actually does / how it works / pitfalls (a soft question) ? Thanks